# How to update EntityFramework Core Code First object including all properties which are also complex objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class `Character`, whose properties are a mix of primitives and complex objects, and some of those objects have properties which are also complex objects.  All of this is represented in the database with each class having its own table, generated through EFCore Code First.

Here's a smaller example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public class Character
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Race { get; set; }
public DeathSaves DeathSaves{ get; set; }
public SavingThrows SavingThrows { get; set; }
}


public class DeathSaves
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool? Success1 { get; set; }
    public bool? Success2 { get; set; }
    public bool? Success3 { get; set; }
    public bool? Failure1 { get; set; }
    public bool? Failure2 { get; set; }
    public bool? Failure3 { get; set; }
}

public class SavingThrows
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SavingThrow Strength { get; set; }
    public SavingThrow Dexterity { get; set; }
    public SavingThrow Constitution { get; set; }
    public SavingThrow Intelligence { get; set; }
    public SavingThrow Wisdom { get; set; }
    public SavingThrow Charisma { get; set; }
}

public class SavingThrow
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool? Proficient { get; set; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see above, my `Character` class contains `DeathSaves` which is an object of primitives, and `SavingThrows` which is an object containing multiple properties who are all `SavingThrow`s.

I know that in my Controller, I've tried

```
var dbchar = _context.Characters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == character.id);
dbchar = character;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

where `character` is sent from the client, but that doesn't update anything in the db.  I've also tried doing `_context.Characters.Attach(character)` and that doesn't seem to update anything either.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "but that doesn't work" could use some elaboration in an [edit]

Comment: Sorry, I edited it to be more clear

Comment: Just because you change the object a variable points to `dbchar = character;` doesn't mean the context has any clue what you're doing. You need to do an update of the instance in the repo.  I'm not 100% sure how it should be done, but for sure if you set every property (and child object property) of `dbchar` to the respective values in `character` THEN `SaveChanges` (or however an Update is supposed to work--maybe attach then save changes? I dunno) that should work...

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935371/how-to-update-a-row-using-entity-framework-code-first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code ...

```
var dbchar = _context.Characters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == character.id);
dbchar = character;
```

... replaces the reference to a character object in the context's cache by a reference to some untracked object. At that moment you lost the handle to the tracked object. It's the same as:

```
var dbchar = new Character { Name = "John" }; // character1
dbchar = new Character { Name = "Pete" }; // character2
```

The object character1 is out of scope, but it's still John.

The right way to do this is either to copy `character`'s values to `dbchar`:

```
var dbchar = _context.Characters.Find(character.id);
db.Entry(cbchar).CurrentValues.SetValues(character);
```

or to attach `character` to the context and mark it as modified:

```
db.Attach(character);
db.Entry(character).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

(Used ef-core v. 1.1.2)